# How to create collapsable grid, table, or columns

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-table

I want to display data in 2 columns.  When there is enough room, the data should look like this:

```
|  data   |  data2  |
|  data3  |  data4  |
|  data5  |  data6  |
```

If the user resizes there window so there is not enough room to display the two columns, I want the data to look like this:

```
|  data   |
|  data2  |
|  data3  |
|  data4  |
|  data5  |
|  data6  |
```

If I were to guess there are already questions and posts online about this, but I don't know what to search.  Links, tips, example code, and guide are all appreciated!

Comment: Using a CSS framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation is perhaps a good idea.

Comment: Also take a look about [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE9 and below you can use `display: flex`

```css
.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .item {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LcsgtaLv/1/

The issue here is that you would have to decide at what size the "break" will happen (at what size the table will start showing up on 2 columns), like we are doing here:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
```

Basically we let them get the 100% of the width until 700px, from there we shut them down to 49% - 2px (because of the border, if there was no border we could've done just 50%).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you can use a table (semantically appropriate for displaying tabular data). On smaller devices, you can change the display layout of the cells to be block instead of their initial table-cell layout.

You can see an example below. It will change to be a single column if the screen gets below 400px (which can be adjusted).

Here is the fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/vz6nLj8a/1/

```css
.responsive-table td {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}
    

@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .responsive-table td {
        display: initial;
        border-right-width: 0px;
    }
        .responsive-table td:last-child {
            border-right: 1px solid;
        }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data5</td>
            <td>data6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```